# Howto get an OAuth token from azure using client secret for a specific scope using MSAL

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-ad-msal

I'm using the following MSAL code to aquire an OAuth token from an azure enterpise application using a client secret.

```cs
            string authority = string.Concat(AzureAuthorityInstance, TenantID);
            appConfidential = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                    .Create(ClientID)
                    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                    .WithAuthority(authority)
                    .WithLegacyCacheCompatibility(false)
                    .Build();

            string[] confidentialScope = new string[] { ".default" };
            return appConfidential.AcquireTokenForClient(confidentialScope).ExecuteAsync().Result;
```

This works and returns a token.

[image]

Instead of using the default scope, i'd like to get a token for a specific scope.

[image]

But if i specify the scope for the api permission, i get the following error.

```
MsalServiceException: AADSTS500011: The resource principal named api://{clientid}/evigetdownload was not found in the tenant named {tenantname}. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.
```

Is it possible to get a token for a specific scope (Based on the API permission) when using a client secret for authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Client Credentials flow, you must use the special ".default" suffix for the scope.
For example if you wanted a token for an API with client ID {clientid}, you could use "{clientid}/.default" as the scope.
Docs for the flow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#first-case-access-token-request-with-a-shared-secret.

The permission in your screenshot is a "delegated" permission which cannot be used in Client Credentials flow.
Those only apply in flows where a user is involved.
You need to register an application permission (aka app role).
Docs for that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps. Make sure to specify "applications" as allowed members.

Comment: In this case i think my problem is actually in the WebAPI servcie where i'm unable to validate this token because of a "IDX10511: Signature validation failed. Keys tried:" error. I'll have a look at the link you've added and will create a new issue if i can't figure out why the token cannot be validated

Comment: The token in your screenshot is a token for Graph API. You need to get a token for your API. Graph uses something a bit different for its signatures. You should not be validating tokens for another API anyway.

Comment: This is the part i don't understand. The scope ".default" does return a token for the grap API which i must not use/validate myself (since it it should be used with the graph api. Do i have to use an app role for this?

Comment: I think what is happening is that ".default" is shorthand for `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`, just like "User.Read" is shorthand for `https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read` scope. You need to specify something like "api-client-id-here/.default" as the scope to get a token for another API. I would recommend adding an app role to the API and assigning it to the client application.